# Unable to open /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h (Permission denied)

Tags: ssh, python

I am getting the following weird **permission denied** problem in python and this is happening whenever I login (SSH) as a normal user (means not root):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 562, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 544, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 271, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 246, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 236, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 543, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 442, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 321, in _init_posix
    raise IOError(msg)
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h (Permission denied)
```

The permission to `/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h` reads like:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 35884 2011-10-04 17:24 /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h

Not sure what is causing this problem, BTW, I know there are similar question to this problem ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9991595/765854) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5345934/765854)) but those are with respect to "No file or directory".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions are ok, but I'm afraid if you need to open it as normal user you'll have to change them.
Now it has 644 (`-rw-r--r--`), so I'd try to set it 645 (`-rw-r--r-x`):

```
sudo chmod 645 /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h
```